# при обновление таблицы получаю ошибку 'student_id' doesn't have a default value'

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, ejb

Пишу программу которая показывает какие дополнительные уроки посещает ученик, вот сущности

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "student")
    @NamedQueries({
            @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findAll", query = "select c from Student 
    c"),
            @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findById",
                    query = "select distinct c from Student c left join fetch 
    c.group t left join fetch c.lesson h where c.studentID = :id"),
            @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findAllWithDetalis",
                    query = "select distinct c from Student c left join fetch 
     c.group t left join fetch c.lesson h")

    })
     public class Student implements Serializable {

        private Long studentID;

        private String firstname;

        private String surname;

        private String patronymic;

        private  Set<Lesson> lesson = new HashSet<>();

        private Group group;

        private Set<Subject> subjects = new HashSet<>();

        private Set<Attendance> attendances = new HashSet<>();

        public Student() {}

        public Student(String surname,String firstname, String patronymic) {
            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.surname = surname;
            this.patronymic = patronymic;

        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "student_id")
        public Long getStudentID() {
            return studentID;
        }

        public void setStudentID(Long studentID) {
            this.studentID = studentID;
        }

        @Column(name = "firstname")
        public String getFirstname() {
            return firstname;
        }

        public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
            this.firstname = firstname;
        }

        @Column(name = "surname")
        public String getSurname() {
            return surname;
        }

        public void setSurname(String surname) {
            this.surname = surname;
        }

        @Column(name = "patronymic")
        public String getPatronymic() {
            return patronymic;
        }

        public void setPatronymic(String patronymic) {
            this.patronymic = patronymic;
        }

        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "student_to_lesson",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "lesson_id"))
        public Set<Lesson> getLesson() {
            return lesson;
        }

        public void setLesson(Set<Lesson> lesson) {
            this.lesson = lesson;
        }

        @OneToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "student_to_attend", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
        "attend_id"))
        public Set<Attendance> getAttendances() {
            return attendances;
        }

        public void setAttendances(Set<Attendance> attendances) {
            this.attendances = attendances;
        }

        public void addAttendances(Attendance attendance){
            attendance.setStudent(this);
            getAttendances().add(attendance);
        }

        public void removeAttedances(Attendance attendance){
            getAttendances().remove(attendance);
        }

        @ManyToOne()
        @JoinTable(name = "student_to_group", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
        "group_id"))
        public Group getGroup() {
            return group;
        }

        public void setGroup(Group group) {
            this.group = group;
        }

       @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
       @JoinTable(name = "student_to_subject",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
       "subject_id"))
        public Set<Subject> getSubjects() {
            return subjects;
        }

        public void setSubjects(Set<Subject> subjects) {
            this.subjects = subjects;
        }

        public void addSubject(Subject subject){
            getSubjects().add(subject);
        }

        public void removeSubject(Subject subject){
            getSubjects().remove(subject);
        }

      }

     @Entity
     @Table(name = "group_")
     @NamedQuery(name = "Group.findByName",
            query = "select distinct c from Group c  where c.nameGroup = :name")
     public class Group implements Serializable {
        private Long groupId;
        private String nameGroup;
        private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();

        public Group() {
        }

        public Group(String nameGroup) {
            this.nameGroup = nameGroup;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "group_id")
        public Long getGroupId() {
            return groupId;
        }

        public void setGroupId(Long groupId) {
            this.groupId = groupId;
        }

        @Column(name = "name_group")
        public String getNameGroup() {
            return nameGroup;
        }

        public void setNameGroup(String nameGroup) {
            this.nameGroup = nameGroup;
        }

        @OneToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "student_to_group",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
       "student_id"))
        public Set<Student> getStudents() {
            return students;
        }

        public void setStudents(Set<Student> students) {
            this.students = students;
        }

        public void addStudent(Student student){
            student.setGroup(this);
            getStudents().add(student);
        }

        public void removeStudent(Student student){
            getStudents().remove(student);
        }
       }

      @Entity
      @Table(name = "subject")
      @NamedQuery(name = "Subject.findByName",
            query = "select distinct c from Subject c  where c.subjectName = 
     :name")
     public class Subject implements Serializable {

        private Long subjectId;
        private String subjectName;
        private Set<Teacher> teacher = new HashSet<>();
        private Lesson lesson;



        public Subject() {
        }

        public Subject(String subjectName) {
            this.subjectName = subjectName;

        }

        @Id
        @Column(name = "subject_id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        public Long getSubjectId() {
            return subjectId;
        }

        public void setSubjectId(Long subjectId) {
            this.subjectId = subjectId;
        }


        @Column(name = "subject_name")
        public String getSubjectName() {
            return subjectName;
        }

        public void setSubjectName(String subjectName) {
            this.subjectName = subjectName;
        }

        @OneToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "teacher_to_subject", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
       "teacher_id"))
        public Set<Teacher> getTeacher() {  return teacher;
        }

        public void setTeacher(Set<Teacher> teacher) {
            this.teacher = teacher;
        }

        public void addTeacher(Teacher teacher){
           teacher.setSubject(this);
            getTeacher().add(teacher);
        }

        public void removeteacher(Teacher teacher){
            getTeacher().remove(teacher);
        }

      }

     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school_journal?useUnicode=true&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" autowire="byType">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>
    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="kz.nis"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
                <prop key = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="kz.nis"/>

</beans>

таблица в БД MySQL
create table  student(
  student_id bigint not null primary key auto_increment
  ,firstname varchar(60) not null
  ,surname varchar (60) not null
  ,patronymic varchar (60) not null
  );

create table  group_ (
  group_id bigint not null primary key auto_increment
  ,name_group varchar(60)not null
);

create table  subject(
   subject_id bigint not null primary key auto_increment
  , subject_name varchar (60) not null

);

create table student_to_group(
  student_id bigint not null
  , group_id bigint not null
  , primary key(student_id, group_id)
  , constraint fk_student_to_group_1 foreign key(student_id)
  references student(student_id)
   , constraint fk_student_to_group_2 foreign key(group_id)
    references group_(group_id)
);

create table student_to_subject(
  student_id bigint not null
  ,subject_id bigint not null
  ,primary key(student_id, subjectt_id)
  ,constraint fk_student_to_subject_1 foreign key(student_id)
    references student(student_id)
  , constraint fk_student_to_subject_2 foreign key(subject_id)
    references subject(subject_id)
);

при выполнение кода
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericXmlApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        context.load("classpath:META-INF/app-context-annotation.xml");
        context.refresh();
        StudentDAO studentDAO = context.getBean("jpaStudentDAO", StudentDAOImpl.class);
        GroupDAO groupDAO = context.getBean("jpaGroupDAO",GroupDAOImpl.class);
        SubjectDAO subjectDAO = context.getBean("jpaSubjectDAO", SubjectDAOImpl.class);
        LessonDAO lessonDAO  = context.getBean("jpaLessonDAO", LessonDAOImpl.class);
        TeacherDAO teacherDAO = context.getBean("jpaTeacherDAO", TeacherDAOImpl.class);


        Student student = studentDAO.findById(1);
        Group group =  groupDAO.findByName("11");
        student.setGroup(group);
        //student.addSubject(subjectDAO.findByName("Physics"));
        studentDAO.save(student);
}
} получаю ошибку
INFO: Student saved with id 1
Hibernate: insert into student_to_group (group_group_id, group_id) values (?, ?)
Oct 29, 2018 7:15:48 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Oct 29, 2018 7:15:48 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch performExecution
ERROR: HHH000315: Exception executing batch [java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Field 'student_id' doesn't have a default value], SQL: insert into student_to_group (group_group_id, group_id) values (?, ?)
Oct 29, 2018 7:15:48 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
Oct 29, 2018 7:15:48 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Field 'student_id' doesn't have a default value
Oct 29, 2018 7:15:48 PM org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl mapManagedFlushFailure
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute batch]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute batch; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute batch
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:765)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:734)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:518)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)
    at kz.nis.data.dao.studentDAO.StudentDAOImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$56c74158.save(<generated>)
    at kz.nis.Main.main(Main.java:35)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute batch
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatch.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.execute(AbstractBatchImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.executeBatch(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:633)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1454)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:511)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3283)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2479)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:98)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Field 'student_id' doesn't have a default value
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:210)
    at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:185)
    at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:192)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createBatchUpdateException(SQLError.java:218)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(ClientPreparedStatement.java:864)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:453)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:839)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:118)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'student_id' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:127)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:960)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1116)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(ClientPreparedStatement.java:843)
    ... 29 more

Process finished with exit code 1

менял значение в sql_mode файле my.ini не помогает.
```

Answer (score 0):

Аннотации нужно указывать над переменной, а не над гетером.
Заменить на:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "student_id")
private Long studentID;

public Long getStudentID() {
    return studentID;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет! поменял но не помогает((